# Issue when a .Net project references another project with lower version and injects the dbcontext from it

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

So, I have the following scenario.

For various reasons I am upgrading a solution to .Net 8 from .Net 6 in steps, meaning I am only upgrading a couple of projects and not all of them at once. For now, I have successfully isolated a few projects that can be upgraded, the criteria being, no remaining .Net6 project should reference the .Net8 projects.

The issue that I am experiencing right now is the following:

1. I have a .Net8 console project which needs to use 2 different EF db contexts;
2. One DbContext is configured in a .Net8 class library and in there I have the .Net 8 ef core packages, and a services extension method that simply does the AddDbContext configuration. Important to mention, in the config I am calling the sqlServerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure() and this works just fine for the .Net8 Db Context;
3. The other DbContext is configured in a .Net6 class library (this library is used by other projects which will not be upgraded just yet so it has to stay on this version) and the efcore packages are the ones intended for .Net 6 . Same story, I have an extension method in which I do the AddDbContext stuff. The configuration is identical between the contexts aside from the schemas that they are using.
4. The problem is that when I start the .Net 8 application and I am trying to **inject** the Context from the .Net6 library, (so the **services.AddDbContext** is going through just fine) the application breaks and I get an exception from the **services.AddDbContext** line that says that I am missing a method : **EnableRetryOnFailure**
   [image]

Please let me know if you have any ideea why this is happening, both .Net6 and .Net8 have the **EnableRetryOnFailure** method so I can't see what I am doing wrong here...
Also, keep in mind, if I simply remove the **EnableRetryOnFailure** method everything runs just fine ... so its not like there is a full incompatibility between the projects.

**Update 1:
Replacing the .EnableRetryOnFailure() with .ExecutionStrategy(my custom strategy or even the SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy) works ... so I am even more confused  as to why I have that problem.